how to understand the v-level of logr pkg in golang
Please forgive if i posted a dumb question, i've been doing some research and even asked ChatGPT, but still couldn't figure it out.

Often we want to log information only when the application in "verbose mode". To write log lines that are more verbose, Logger has a V() method. The higher the V-level of a log line, the less critical it is considered. Log-lines with V-levels that are not enabled (as per the LogSink) will not be written. Level V(0) is the default, and logger.V(0).Info() has the same meaning as logger.Info(). Negative V-levels have the same meaning as V(0). Error messages do not have a verbosity level and are always logged.
Where we might have written:
if flVerbose >= 2 {
log.Printf("an unusual thing happened") }
We can write:
logger.V(2).Info("an unusual thing happened")

Above is from the document of logr, my understanding is that logger.V(2).Info("an unusual thing happened") will only print if the current verbosity level is set to higher than 2, in the case of if flVerbose >= 2 { log.Printf("an unusual thing happened") } it is obvious that somewhere in the code, i need to set flVerbose to 2 or higher, but with the v-level, how should i set the verbosity level? Or did i completely misunderstood the above document?
Thanks in advance!

Via command line arguments.

With logr, this functionality is part of the underlying implementation of logr.Sink.
For example (Go playground):
import (
    "log"
    "log/slog"
    "os"

    "github.com/go-logr/logr"
    "github.com/go-logr/stdr"
)

func main() {
    l1 := stdr.New(log.Default())
    stdr.SetVerbosity(4)

    logSomething(l1)

    handler := slog.NewTextHandler(os.Stdout, &slog.HandlerOptions{Level: slog.LevelDebug})
    l2 := logr.FromSlogHandler(handler)

    logSomething(l2)
}

func logSomething(l logr.Logger) {
    l.V(4).Info("Debug msg", "key", "value")
    l.V(0).Error(nil, "Error msg", "key", "value")
}

creates a standard logger sink with level 4 and a slog sink with level 4. When you remove stdr.SetVerbosity(4) and Level: slog.LevelDebug you'll get sinks with default Level (0) and the debug messages won't appear.
